# Why does the Minotaur I wear a yellow jacket that "banana-peels" off as it launches?

Tags: launch, identify-this-object, military, icbm

Videos available of the recent Minotaur I launch at Wallops for NROL-111 show a yellow jacket on most of the four stage SRB-to-orbit launch vehicle. I read or heard somewhere that wires attached to the ground "banana-peel" the yellow jacket off the rocket as it launches.

I could imagine an insulating jacket on a rocket with cryopropellants, perhaps with clean dry air blown underneath to prevent ice build up, but I can't imagine why this cover would be necessary on an SRB whose heritage is a (presumably) robust ICBM.

**Question:** Why does the Minotaur I wear a yellow jacket that "banana-peels" off as it launches?

---

NASA Wallops video "NRO L-111 Launch" cued at about 12 seconds before launch, with a lot of introductory information:

---

cued at `28:15` There is a lot of cogent discussion in the video before the launch which may be helpful; for some inexplicable reason the NASA Spaceflight narrators suddenly and temporarily loose composure just moments before launch:

---

[image: The Near Field Infrared Experiment (NFIRE) military satellite in April 2007 with a Minotaur-1 missile]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:NFIRE1.jpg)

Image information google-translated from German:

> The Near Field Infrared Experiment (NFIRE) military satellite in April 2007 with a Minotaur-1 missile

Comment: That last photo is really nice.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ya, after the fact I happened to notice the flexible ducting connecting to the bottom of the jacket(s).

Comment: Your second video explains the history/design and reason for the jacket (which is as Organic Marble says below) from approximately 5:50.

Comment: @RobGilliam lol! Maybe I *should* start watching the videos in the questions.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The jacket is to control the Propellant Mean Bulk Temperature, a critical factor in solid rocket motor performance.

The silos for the missiles that the launcher was derived from were air-conditioned for this reason.

> the Minuteman boosters in the
> Lower Stack were designed to be launch (sic) from a climate
> controlled silo with virtually no outside weather effects
> until launch.

For pad launch,

> **Therefore, continuous temperature control
> was required**....
> ...**the tight
> booster temperature constraints could easily be broken.**
> It was decided that whatever system was used it had to
> be quickly removable - to ensure the availability of the
> full launch window - and quickly replaced - in case of
> launch abort. After trading off various options, the
> approach finally implemented was an inflated, insulated
> thermal blanket. The blanket can be seen in Figure 16
> as the yellow cover over the lower portion of the
> Launch Vehicle.

(emphasis mine. figure 16 omitted, it was very low res, the picture in the question is far superior)

[Demonstration of a New Smallsat Launch Vehicle: The Orbital/Suborbital Program (OSP)
Space Launch Vehicle Inaugural Mission Results](http://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2038&context=smallsat)

Comment: What was the tolerable temperature range for the booster? I didn't see any numbers from skimming the linked paper. (Main reason I ask is because requiring a very specific temperature range seems different from the SLS SRBs, and I'm curious if the latter are more tolerant for some reason)

Comment: @DylanSp for a time I worked on shuttle day of launch, and we were constantly dealing with PMBT on the boosters. We got L-12 day and L-3 day predictions from Thiokol on what the PMBT would be at launch to run our sims. A major reason for the shuttle's adaptive throttle in the thrust bucket was because of SRB performance changes due to PMBT.  This experience is why I knew what the blanket had to be for although I know nothing about Minotaur.

Comment: @DylanSp It sounds like there's a new question or two there!

Comment: @uhoh There's an existing unanswered question, https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12008/13208. I'll probably post an additional question or two when I can.