# What is an "Aceteria improved Ryan suborbital sounding rocket"?

Tags: launch, identify-this-object, sounding-rocket, outreach

[Why does the Minotaur I wear a yellow jacket that "banana-peels" off as it launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53727/12102) links to the NASA Wallops video [NRO L-111 Launch](https://youtu.be/ePwcJYE_BgI?t=2044) (already cued at the statement in question).

At the end of the video at the video time of `34:04` the announcer says (according to the closed captions; I wasn't able to make out anything clearer by listening):

> Mission information including photos will be available on NRO, NASA Wallops and Orthogram websites and their respective Facebook and Twitter accounts.
>
> The next launch from Wallops is an aceteria imrpoved ryan suborbital sounding rocket, carrying the Rock-on educational payload.
>
> Launch is scheduled for 8 AM Thursday, June 24th. Thanks for joining us today.

**Question:** What is an "Aceteria improved Ryan suborbital sounding rocket"? Exactly what rocket will launch next from Wallops?

---

Potentially helpful:

- [What's up with the "What's Up at Wallops" app?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26246/12102)

---

[image: screenshot from NASA Wallops video NRO L-111 Launch]

Comment: I wouldn't expect anything useful from automatically generated captions if I'm not able to make out a clear word by listening - and that's even though I have real issues understanding some washed-out accents...

Comment: I guess the relevant parts are "Terrier" and "improved Orion" (both names of sounding rockets), but there are a few syllables I don't get.

Comment: @asdfex, oh, Terrier as in the first part of [Why a Terrier Malemute?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21931/12102) "Terrier Improved-Malemute" That makes sense.

Comment: Yes, there is an "Terrier Improved Orion", see references here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrier_Orion

Comment: @asdfex you nailed it https://www.nasa.gov/centers/wallops/home

Comment: Feel free to write an answer, maybe with a full transcript of the section and some more information about the next launch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The announcer's diction is quite poor; what's being transcribed as

`an aceteria improved ryan suborbital sounding rocket`

Is almost certainly

`a NASA Terrier-Improved Orion suborbital sounding rocket`.

(h/t asdfex)

Terrier-Improved Orion ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrier_Orion), [Gunter's](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau_det/terrier_orion.htm)) is a two-stage, spin-stabilized sounding rocket. "Improved Orion" refers to the [upper stage](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau/orion.htm), which has been used as a sounding rocket by itself as well.

Wallops has an article on their website [about the June 24 RockOn launch being referred to](https://www.nasa.gov/wallops/2021/feature/student-experiments-to-blast-off-from-nasa-wallops). (h/t Organic Marble)

The RockOn program is a [recurring annual workshop](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/wallops/education/students/opportunities/rockon/index.html) for students to create experiments to fly on sounding rockets; RockOn has used the Terrier-Improved Orion sounding rocket several times before.